# cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have a fragment for displaying data with many dynamic textViews,when implements setOnClickListener for dynamic view get this error:

```
com.Package.activity.DashboardActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
```

Activity :DasgboardActivity : load fragment in frameLayout

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new TestFragment()).commit();
```

Fragment

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

  CreateView createView;
List<Model> listData=new ArrayList();
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  createView = new CreateView();
  listData=db.getAllData();
  createView.makeView(getActivity,listData);
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}

}
```

CreateView class: for creating dynamic views:

```
  public View makeView(Context context, List<Model> words_List) {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);

        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            for (Model w : words_List) {

                TextView textView = new TextView(context);

                textView.setText(w.getW_text()+"");
                textView.setId(w.getW_id());
                textView.setTag(w.getW_id());


                    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


       textView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context);


                linearLayout.addView(textView);
            }


        return linearLayout;
    }
```

in this line i got error :
   textView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) context);

My code completely working on activity but in fragment i have error

How i must fix my bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of OnClickListener interface in CreateView class like this :

```
   public class CreateView {

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = null;

        public CreateView(View.OnClickListener  listener){
            this.onClickListener = listener ; 
        }


        public View createLabelForMainWordsInOneLine(Context context, List<Model> words_List) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            for (Model w : words_List) {

                TextView textView = new TextView(context);

                textView.setText(w.getW_text() + "");
                textView.setId(w.getW_id());
                textView.setTag(w.getW_id());


                textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                textView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);


                linearLayout.addView(textView);
            }


            return linearLayout;
        }
    }
```

Then , You can instanciate CreateView like this :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  createView = new CreateView(this);
  listData=db.getAllData();
  createView.makeView(getActivity,listData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the fragment that implements View.OnClickListener, not the activity. 
Do this instead:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment{

    CreateView createView;
    List<Model> listData=new ArrayList();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         createView = new CreateView();
         listData=db.getAllData();
         createView.makeView(getActivity,listData);
    }


    View.OnClickListener textViewClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //your listener code here
        }
    };
}
```

And when you need to set the OnClickListener to the textView, use

```
textView.setOnClickListener(textViewClickListener);
```

Comment: how to pass textViewClickListener to CreateView class via parameters?

Comment: I see what you're saying. If CreateView class is independent of the fragment and it can't access the OnClickListener,  define the textViewClickListener in the CreateView class instead of inside the fragment.